# List: Detecting switches from less than zero to greater than zero

Tags: vb.net, algorithm, linq, list

is there any existing linq function or similiar functions to detect how often values in an ordered list changes from less than zero to greater than zero?

As example, values:

```
5
2
-2
-5
8  <--- First
6
2
0
1
-3
-5
-3
2  <--- Second
```

Total count: 2

Comment: _"From less than zero to greater than zero"_? You mean: _from greater than zero to less than zero_ instead, or where does your list start?

Comment: ...and how about an initially negative number?

Comment: sorry, I've updated the list... it seems I'm already a little bit confused about it... lol

Comment: So what about the list `1, -1, 0, 1` - that has no change or one change?

Comment: You should update your Q; since that not what your current description really suggests - no value-transition ever goes from negative to positive, after all.

Comment: (e.g. Skeet's answer below does not take this into account)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure - it's certainly easy if you're using .NET 4 or higher, using `Zip`:

```
// TODO: Consider how you want to handle 0 itself
var count = list.Zip(list.Skip(1), (x, y) => new { x, y })
                .Count(pair => pair.x > 0 && pair.y < 0);
```

That shouldn't be hard to convert into VB if you know VB well :)

Alternatively, if you've really got a list, you can just do it "manually" pretty easily without LINQ:

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count - 1; i++)
{
    if (list[i] > 0 && list[i + 1] < 0)
    {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Zip looks very interessting.. but it's also a bit complex so I think the "manually way" will be better here, specially for other developers reading my code. Converting to VB.NET isn't a problem, thanks

Comment: your for loop will cause an exception, because in the if you are accessing list[i + 1], which is not available in the last step.

Comment: @FelixC: It should be, given that my loop condition is `i < list.Count - 1`.

Comment: Ah, you're right.. i translated it to VB.NET and there is only <= available for the loop (For i As Integer = 0 To X)

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this in one pass using `Aggregate`:

```
seq.Aggregate(new { Count=0, LastN = 0}, (state, n) => new { 
        Count =  state.Count + (n > 0 && state.LastN < 0 ? 1 : 0), 
        LastN = n == 0 ? state.LastN : n
    }).Count
```

This takes into account your wish to include "gradual" transitions such as -1,0,1.

However, a foreach may be easier, simply because it's more conventional.  It'll also be faster:

```
var count = 0;
var lastN = 0;
foreach(var n in seq) {
    if(n > 0 && lastN < 0)
        count++;
    if (n != 0)
        lastN = n;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the C#; I'm not really well versed in VB.

Comment: That is no problem, I know c# very well, but I'm forced to code in VB.NET here :D thanks for your answer